# Npqsql Stored Procedure Returns Multiple REFCURSOR

Tags: c#, postgresql, stored-procedures, npgsql

I am having several issues calling stored procedures from .NET/C# using Npgsql. I am getting different errors at times from Operation already in progress, to now row available, to column out of range, must be between 0 and 0. However this is the main stack trace I am seeing from NUnit.

```
System.InvalidOperationException : An operation is already in progress.

   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.StartUserAction(ConnectorState newState)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.ExecuteInternalCommand(SimpleFrontendMessage message, Boolean withTimeout)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Rollback()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlTransaction.Rollback()
   at Omega.Data.DAO.PatientShapeDao.GetShapeData(Int64 shapeId) in c:\Users\jkratz\Projects\omega\Omega\data\DAO\PatientShapeDao.cs:line 62
   at Omega.Tests.DAO.PostgresDaoTests.TestGetShapeData() in c:\Users\jkratz\Projects\omega\Omega.Tests\DAO\PostgresDaoTests.cs:line 26
```

I have the following stored procedure in Postgres:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.getpatientshapedata(p_shapeid bigint)
  RETURNS SETOF refcursor AS
$BODY$
    DECLARE
        v_shapecursor REFCURSOR;
        v_shapefilecursor REFCURSOR;
    BEGIN

      OPEN v_shapecursor FOR
        select * from patientshape where id = p_shapeid;
      RETURN NEXT v_shapecursor;

      OPEN v_shapefilecursor FOR
        select * from patientshapefile where patientshapeid = p_shapeid;
      RETURN NEXT v_shapefilecursor;

    END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
```

It returns two refcursors at the moment.

I have the following Dao object in my application.

```
public class PatientShapeDao
    {
        private NpgsqlConnection _dbHandle;
        private readonly string _connectionString;

        public PatientShapeDao()
        {
            OmegaConnectionString connectionString = Transform.getInstance.LoadOmegaConnection();

            _connectionString = string.Format("Server={0};User Id={1};Password={2};Database={3}", 
                connectionString.Host, connectionString.UserId, connectionString.Password, connectionString.Database);
        }

        public void GetShapeData(long shapeId)
        {
            NpgsqlTransaction transaction;

            // open connection
            _dbHandle = new NpgsqlConnection(_connectionString);
            _dbHandle.Open();

            // begin transaction
            transaction = _dbHandle.BeginTransaction();

            try
            {
                // call stored procedure
                NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand("getpatientshapedata", _dbHandle);
                command.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("p_shapeid", shapeId));
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                NpgsqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();

                // read result sets
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", dataReader[0], dataReader[1]);
                }

                dataReader.NextResult();

                // read result sets
                while (dataReader.Read())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}", dataReader[0], dataReader[1]);
                }

                transaction.Commit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                transaction.Rollback();
            }
            finally
            {
                _dbHandle.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your stack trace shows that the exception is being thrown from Rollback, which means there was some earlier exception in your code which you haven't posted.

Regardless, you need to place your NpgsqlCommand and NpgsqlDataReader in a using so that they get properly disposed before reaching the catch block.